# How to add an arbitrary field with XML::Compile::WSDL11 (mistake: tag `param' not used at...)

Tags: xml, perl

I'm trying to use the module [`XML::Compile::WSDL11`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML%3a%3aCompile%3a%3aWSDL11) to create a SOAP message in base of a wsdl file.
In the xsd definitions there is a parameter called `UserArea` that is supposed to hold arbitrary fields (extensions):

```
<xsd:element name="UserArea" type="UserAreaType"/>
<xsd:complexType name="UserAreaType">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:any namespace="##any" processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

So I can create manually a valid xml like:

```
<ProcessAssessmentOrder>
  ...
  <DataArea>
   ...
   <AssessmentOrder>
     ...
     <UserArea xmlns:xxx="http://example.com">
        <xxx:someURL>http://someurl.example.com</xxx:someURL>
      </UserArea>
    </AssessmentOrder>
  </DataArea>
</ProcessAssessmentOrder>
```

That works and validates.
However trying to use `XML::Compile::WSDL11` I got the error:

```
mistake: tag `xxx:SomeURL' not used at {http://www.hr-xml.org/3}ProcessAssessmentOrder/DataArea/AssessmentOrder/CustomerParty/PartyReportingIDs/UserArea
```

And the parameter is not in the generated xml.

So far this is my Perl code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use DateTime;
use XML::Compile::Transport::SOAPHTTP;
use XML::Compile::SOAP11;
use XML::Compile::WSDL11;

my %args = (
  releaseID => '3.3',
  ApplicationArea => {
    CreationDateTime => DateTime->now,
  },
  DataArea => {
    Process => {},
    AssessmentOrder => {
      UserArea => {
        'xxx:SomeURL' => 'www.example.com',
      },
    },
  },
);


my $wsdl_path = '/home/david/HR-XML-3_3/Assessments/org_hr-xml/3_3/WebServices/WSDL/AssessmentOrder.wsdl';
my $wsdl  = XML::Compile::WSDL11->new($wsdl_path);
import_definitions($wsdl, '/home/david/HR-XML-3_3/Assessments/');
$wsdl->compileCalls(
  port     => 'AssessmentOrder_Port',
  endpoint => 'http://127.0.0.1/xxx',
);

my($response, $trace) = $wsdl->call('ProcessAssessmentOrder', %args);

sub import_definitions { 
  my($wsdl, $path) = @_;
  opendir (my $dh, $path);
  while (my $file = readdir($dh)) {
    next if ($file eq '.' || $file eq '..');
    if (-d "$path/$file") {
      import_definitions($wsdl, "$path/$file");
    }
    elsif ($file =~ m#\.xsd$#) {
      $wsdl->importDefinitions("$path/$file");
    }
  }
  closedir($dh);
};
```

How to make it work to get the xml having the line

```
<xxx:someURL>http://someurl.example.com</xxx:someURL>
```

¿·_·?

Answer (score 0):

Yo can try adding this:

```
my $myns = 'http://example.com';
$wsdl->prefixes => { $myns  => [ uri => $myns, prefix => 'xxx' ] };
```

seen at [http://search.cpan.org/](http://search.cpan.org/~markov/XML-Compile-1.44/lib/XML/Compile/Schema.pod#Administration)

Answer (score 0):

If I read things right at http://lists.scsys.co.uk/pipermail/xml-compile/2009-July/000250.html, I think XML::Compile doesn't support the xsd:any element.  Further than that, I can't say, as I'm wresting with a similar issue myself.